# Error in MySQL syntax while using raw command in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-views, mysql-error-1064

In a function in views.py, I am trying to access the header columns(column names) of a table using a SQL query, and use it. I am using a MYSQL database for my Django project. However, I am getting the following error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"

My code:

views.py

```
def get_columns(request):
  # some other code
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute("DESCRIBE %s", [table_name])
  for column in cursor.fetchall():
     #use columns extracted here
 return (Some appropriate response)
```

Can someone please help me figure out the problem here?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. I've simplified the code here a bit, but the table is dynamic so I won't know the columns beforehand .

Comment: Assuming you are using from django.db import connection, the code should work, but you need to show more information. For instance, what string you are getting for cursor.execute("DESCRIBE %s", [table_name]). Alternatively, you could use model._meta.get_all_field_names() to get a list of all the fields in a model class

Comment: I have imported connection, yet it doesn't work. The error which is shown is django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table_name'' at line 1")